# uso de malloc / free

Tags: c

No entiendo por qué este código funciona:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  float* a;
  float* b;

  a=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*10);

  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    a[i]=i;

  b = a;

  free(a);

  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("%f\n",b[i]);



return 0;   
}
```

Yo esperaba que después de liberar la memoria reservada para "a", me diera un error de segmentación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando liberas memoria con `free(a)`, simplemente se marca como libre la dirección a que apunta `a`, lo que la deja disponible para ser usada en futuros `malloc()`, pero no borra esa memoria o la hace inaccesible.

Ya que el puntero `b` aún apuntaba a ella, puedes ver (de momento) los valores que hay allí (de hecho, aún siguen siendo accesibles a través de `a`, puesto que `free()` no modifica ese puntero, no podría aunque quisiera porque lo recibe por copia).

Si más adelante el programa hiciera otros `malloc()` sería enteramente posible que se reasignara esa zona, y entonces `b` vería los nuevos datos que fueras guardando en ella.

En algunas ocasiones, es posible que `free()`, además de actualizar las estructuras de datos que el runtime de C mantiene para saber qué direcciones están libres o usadas, haga llamadas al operativo para liberar efectivamente esa memoria. En ese caso el operativo actualzaría la tabla de páginas del sistema y la dirección en cuestión sería realmente inaccesible para el progama, que al intentarlo generaría un segfault. En general el comportamiento de `free()` puede depender de la implementación del compilador y del runtime. No se garantiza qué pasará si intentas acceder a una zona liberada con `free()` (pero tampoco se garantiza, como ves, que se vaya a generar un error de protección).

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia, todo claro.